# How to stop container in containerd/ctr

Tags: docker, containerd

What is the equivalent of `docker stop [containerID]` using ctr? I can't seem to find it via contianer option or I am missing some ctr concepts...

Comment: I am not sure if i'm doing this right, so far I can accomplish this by 

```ctr --namespace 'k8s.io' t kill [ID] && ctr --namespace 'k8s.io' c rm [ID]```

Answer (score 7):

check the tasks which are running:

```
ctr task ls
```

Then you will see something like that

> TASK    PID      STATUS
>
> ```
> v0      62166    RUNNING
> ```

Do

```
ctr task kill v0
```

or

```
ctr task kill -s SIGKILL v0
```

Comment: For better readability, please avoid using abbreviations and try to format code and command lines by surrounding them with backquote.